# Set form input as variable in get_queryset

Tags: django, django-forms

## AIM

I wish to render **results.html** with all the `locations` associated with the `search_text` entered by the User.

To do so, I am attempting to filter the results in `get_quersey()`, but am struggling to set the `form_input` variable. I am currently using `form_input = self.request.GET.get('search_text')`.

## CODE

**models.py**

```
import re

from django.db import models
from twython import Twython


class Location(models.Model):
    """ Model representing a Location (which is attached to Hashtag objects
    through a M2M relationship) """

    name = models.CharField(max_length=1400)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Hashtag(models.Model):
    """ Model representing a specific Hashtag serch by user """

    search_text = models.CharField(max_length=140, primary_key=True)
    locations = models.ManyToManyField(Location, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        """ String for representing the Model object (search_text) """
        return self.search_text

    def display_locations(self):
        """ Creates a list of the locations attached to the Hashtag model """
        return list(self.locations.values_list('name', flat=True).all())
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from django.forms import ModelForm
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

from .models import Location, Hashtag


class SearchHashtagForm(ModelForm):
    ''' ModelForm for user to search by hashtag '''

    def clean_hashtag(self):
        data = self.cleaned_data['search_text']
        # Check search_query doesn't include '#'. If so, remove it.
        if data[0] == '#':
            data = data[1:]
        return data

    class Meta:
        model = Hashtag
        fields = ['search_text',]
        labels = {'search_text':_('Hashtag Search'), }
        help_texts = { 'search_text': _('Enter a hashtag to search.'), }
```

**views.py**

```
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render
from django.urls import reverse
from django.views import generic
from django.views.generic.edit import FormView

from .models import Location, Hashtag
from .forms import SearchHashtagForm


class HashtagSearch(FormView):
    """ FormView for user to enter hashtag search query """

    template_name = 'mapping_twitter/hashtag_search_form.html'
    form_class = SearchHashtagForm

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('mapping_twitter:results')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        # the method is called when valid form data has been POSTed, and returns an HttpResponse
        form.clean_hashtag()
        form.save()
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def form_invalid(self, form):
        # Check if the search_text is invalid because it already exists in the database. If so, render results.html with that search_text
        search_text = self.request.POST.get('search_text')
        if search_text and Hashtag.objects.filter(pk=search_text).exists():
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('mapping_twitter:results'))
        else:
            return super(HashtagSearch, self).form_invalid(form)


class SearchResultsView(generic.ListView):
    """ Generic class-based view listing search results of locations """
    model = Hashtag
    template_name = 'mapping_twitter/results.html'

    def get_queryset(self, **kwargs):

        # ISSUE: restrict the search_text displayed on results.html to the 'search_text' entered by the user
        qs = Hashtag.objects.all()

        form_input = self.request.GET.get('search_text')

        if form_input:
            qs = qs.filter(search_text__iexact=form_input)

        return qs


    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(SearchResultsView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['search_text'] = Hashtag.objects.all()
        return context
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `get_context_data` you don't use `get_queryset` method at all. You just write another query which fetch all Hashtag objects. You should rewrite it to this:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(SearchResultsView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['search_text'] = self.get_queryset()
    return context
```

Note `self.get_queryset()` is using instead of `Hashtag.objects.all()`.

Also note to use `self.request.GET.get('search_text')` you need to pass `search_text` as GET argument when performing redirect in `HashtagSearch` view:

```
class HashtagSearch(FormView):
    """ FormView for user to enter hashtag search query """

    template_name = 'mapping_twitter/hashtag_search_form.html'
    form_class = SearchHashtagForm

    def get_success_url(self):
        return '{}?search_text={}'.format(reverse('mapping_twitter:results'),  self.request.POST.get('search_text'))
```

**UPD**

But isntead of two views I recommend you to use single `ListView`. Just add GET form to your `results.html` and simple override `get_queryset` method:

```
# template 
<form method="GET" action="">
      <input type="text"  name="search_text" placeholder="Search post" value="{{ request.GET.search_text }}">
      <input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>


# view
class SearchResultsView(generic.ListView):
    """ Generic class-based view listing search results of locations """
    model = Hashtag
    template_name = 'mapping_twitter/results.html'

    def get_queryset(self, **kwargs):

        # ISSUE: restrict the search_text displayed on results.html to the 'search_text' entered by the user
        qs = Hashtag.objects.all()

        form_input = self.request.GET.get('search_text')

        if form_input:
            qs = qs.filter(search_text__iexact=form_input)

        return qs
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try to figure it out :)

Is using `self.request.GET.get('search_text')` and passing `search_text` in `get_success_url` best practice? Or, is there another simplier way to set the `form_input` variable in `get_queryset`?

Comment: @ycrad I would recommend you to use single `ListView`. Add to the result.html template simple GET form with single textbox. And override `get_queryset` as you did in SearchResultsView`.

Comment: Because my `Form` may either POST or GET (depending on whether the `search_text` already exists in the `Hashtag` model) would that approach work?

As a preliminary task, I manually set the `form_input` to a string of 'trump': 'qs = `Hashtag.objects.filter(search_text__iexact='trump')`. That code did as expected and returned all the `locations` associated with 'trump' in `Hashtag` model.

Therefore, I presumed that I'd be able to complete the aim by simply setting `form_input` in `get_queryset()` in the similar way I set `search_text` in `form_invalid()`?